# Pandas DataFrame column from a tuple

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas, tuples

I have a dictionary:

```
employer =  
{'CrntEmp_city': ('XXX', 'XXX'),
'CrntEmp_cntry': ('XXX', 'XXX'),
'CrntEmp_orgNm': ('XXXX LLC', 'YYYY LLC'),
'CrntEmp_orgPK': ('1234567891', '1234567899'),
'CrntEmp_postlCd': ('12345', '12345'),
'CrntEmp_state': ('AK', 'AK'),
'CrntEmp_str1': ('999 XXX', '999 XXX'),
'CrntEmp_str2': ('XXXX', 'XXXX')}
```

and I want to read this into a **DataFrame** with **one row and the eight columns** corresponding to the keys. But however I try this, pandas will always give me two columns (by splitting the tuple where the comma is). Example:

```
pd.DataFrame([tuple(i) for i in employ.values()])


returns 
    0           1
0   XXXX LLC    YYYY LLC
1   XXXX        XXXX
2   999 XXX     999 XXX
3   XXX         XXX
4   12345       12345
5   XXX         XXX
6   AK          AK
7   1234567891  1234567899
```

What I want is this:

```
     0                    1
 0  (XXXX LLC, YYYY LLC)  (XXXX, XXXX)
 etc.
```

Hence this command fails:

```
pd.DataFrame([tuple(i) for i in  employ.values()],columns=employ.keys(),index=[0])
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically want something like:  `pd.DataFrame({'col1': [(a, b)], 'col2': [(c, d)]})`

You can achieve that using a dictionary comprehension as follows in Python 2. For Python 3, use `employer.iter()` instead.

```
>>> pd.DataFrame({k: [tuple(v)] for k, v in employer.iteritems()})

  CrntEmp_city CrntEmp_cntry         CrntEmp_orgNm             CrntEmp_orgPK CrntEmp_postlCd CrntEmp_state        CrntEmp_str1  CrntEmp_str2
0   (XXX, XXX)    (XXX, XXX)  (XXXX LLC, YYYY LLC)  (1234567891, 1234567899)  (12345, 12345)      (AK, AK)  (999 XXX, 999 XXX)  (XXXX, XXXX)
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. Pandas really should have an option for that built in.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `iteritems()`:

```
import pandas as pd

employer = {'CrntEmp_city': ('XXX', 'XXX'),
'CrntEmp_cntry': ('XXX', 'XXX'),
'CrntEmp_orgNm': ('XXXX LLC', 'YYYY LLC'),
'CrntEmp_orgPK': ('1234567891', '1234567899'),
'CrntEmp_postlCd': ('12345', '12345'),
'CrntEmp_state': ('AK', 'AK'),
'CrntEmp_str1': ('999 XXX', '999 XXX'),
'CrntEmp_str2': ('XXXX', 'XXXX')}

print pd.DataFrame([i for i in employer.iteritems()])
                 0                         1
0    CrntEmp_orgNm      (XXXX LLC, YYYY LLC)
1     CrntEmp_str2              (XXXX, XXXX)
2     CrntEmp_str1        (999 XXX, 999 XXX)
3    CrntEmp_cntry                (XXX, XXX)
4  CrntEmp_postlCd            (12345, 12345)
5     CrntEmp_city                (XXX, XXX)
6    CrntEmp_state                  (AK, AK)
7    CrntEmp_orgPK  (1234567891, 1234567899)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I need one row and the columns read in when calling pd.DataFrame as part of my function. This solution would take more than one step to get the data into the desirable format.

Answer (score 0):

Try forcing the data to be one column by first defining it as a Series:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame(data=pd.Series(employer.values()))
```

Then the output matches your example desired result (which does not match your original description, but I assume you can take it from here).

```
                          0
0      (XXXX LLC, YYYY LLC)
1              (XXXX, XXXX)
2        (999 XXX, 999 XXX)
3                (XXX, XXX)
4            (12345, 12345)
5                (XXX, XXX)
6                  (AK, AK)
7  (1234567891, 1234567899)
```